# Execution of tasks with different timeframes

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, apscheduler

I have a blockchain bot that can interact with the blockchain. There are routes that consist of multiple actions (swap, liquidity, mint, etc.). A user selects a route, and then the actions are recorded in a database, and the date for each action to start execution is calculated. For example, Client_1 selects Route_1, and 10 actions are recorded in the database, each with its calculated start time. The code then starts executing each action according to its scheduled time. Client_2 selects Route_2, and another 7 actions are similarly calculated, added to the queue, and initiated. All of this should work in parallel, and if the execution times of two users' actions coincide.

I was considering using apscheduler or celery/rabbit. Which of these options is better? Or are there other solutions?"